# Probability of first increase in ordering of iid random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> What is the probability that the first $n-1$ terms of iid Unif(0,1) random draws are in decreasing order, but the first $n$ terms are not?
> $$

I know that due to exchangability, $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}<X_{2}<\cdots<X_{n-1})=\frac{1}{n-1!}$. Why can't a similar exchangability argument hold to show that $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}>\cdots>X_{n-1}<X_{n})=\frac{1}{n!}$? My reasoning is that the distribution of $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ is symmetric, so no matter which permutation of the random variables exist in the random vector, they will all have the same probability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $P(X_i=X_j)=0$ for every $ i \ne j$, we infer that $$\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}>\cdots>X_{n-1}<X_{n})=  $$ $$
\mathbb{P}(X_{1}> \cdots>X_{n-1})-\mathbb{P}(X_{1}> \cdots>X_{n-1}>X_{n})
=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{n-1}{n!} \,.$$

$ \,$

Another way to reach the same conclusion is to observe that the event
$X_{1}>X_{2}>\cdots>X_{n-1}<X_{n}$ represents $n-1$ permutations of the $n$ variables, determined by what is the first $k \in [1,n-1]$ such that $X_n>X_k$.

Comment: nice! so elegant!

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}<X_{2}<\cdots<X_{n-1})$ the permuted events all add up to the whole space. But in $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>X_{2}>\cdots>X_{n-1}<X_{n})$ the permuattions don't exhaust the sample space. For example, $(X_1>X_2<X_3)\cup (X_2>X_3<X_1)\cup (X_1>X_3<X_2)\cup (X_2>X_1<X_3)\cup (X_3>X_2<X_1)\cup (X_3>X_1<X_2)$ does not include the event $(X_1>X_2>X_3)$ or $(X_1<X_2<X_3)$.

Answer (score 2):

So lets define the event where the first $t$ terms are monotonic decreasing
as $D_t:=X_1 > X_2 > X_3>...>X_t$ where $1 \leq t\leq n$.

As you pointed out, by exchangeability:

$$P(D_n)=\frac{1}{n!} $$

Let's choose a value $k\geq 2$, what we want to know is this:

$$P\left(D_{k-1}\; \cap\;X_k > X_{k-1} \right) = P(D_{k-1})P(X_k>X_{k-1}|D_{k-1})$$

We already know that $P(D_{k-1}) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$, so now we need to get $P(X_k>X_{k-1}|D_{k-1})$.

What we need to know is the probability that $X_k > X_{k-1}$ knowing that $X_{k-1}$ is the last term in a decreasing sequence of $k-1$ terms. Intuitively,

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} P(X_k > X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}) = 1$$

Since $X_{k-1}|D_{k-1} \to 0 \;a.s.$

Since $X_k$ is iid $U(0,1)$ we know that $P(X_k > z) = 1- P(X_k \leq z) = 1-z$. So, we need to average over all possibilities for the value of $X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}$.

$$P(X_k>X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}) = 1-\int_0^1 xP(X_{k-1}=x|D_{k-1})dx = 1- E[X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}]$$

Therefore, we need to know the expected value of the 1st order statistic out of $k-1$ order statistics (i.e., $E[X_{(1,k-1)}]$). This is a common fact about iid samples of $U(0,1)$ random variables:

$$E[X_{(i,n)}] = \frac{i}{n+1} \implies E[X_{(1,k-1)}] = \frac{1}{k}$$

Putting this together, we get:

$$P(X_k>X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}) = 1- E[X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}] = 1 - \frac{1}{k}$$
$$ \implies P(D_{k-1})P(X_k>X_{k-1}|D_{k-1}) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right) = \frac{1}{k(k-2)!}$$

So we get:

$$P\left(D_{k-1}\; \cap\;X_k > X_{k-1} \right) = \frac{1}{k(k-2)!} \;\;\square$$

---

As an aside, you can check this numerically with this little python program:

```
from math import factorial
from random import uniform

U = lambda: uniform(0,1)

def count_decrease(seq):
    count = 2
    prev_val = seq[0]
    for i in seq[1:]:
        if i < prev_val:
            count += 1
            prev_val = i
            continue
        break
    return count

def p(k):
    return (1/k)*(1/factorial(k-2))

def get_sample(seq_len):
    return [U() for _ in range(seq_len)]

SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 30
SAMPLE_SIZE = 10000
Z = [count_decrease(get_sample(SEQUENCE_LENGTH)) for _ in range(SAMPLE_SIZE)]
dist_sample = {i:Z.count(i)/SAMPLE_SIZE for i in range(min(Z),max(Z)+1)} 
dist_theoretical = {i:round(p(i),6) for i in range(min(Z),max(Z)+1)}
```

I got this:

```
>>> dist_sample
{2: 0.4984, 3: 0.3312, 4: 0.1279, 5: 0.0329, 6: 0.0081, 7: 0.001, 8: 0.0004, 9: 0.0001}
>>> dist_theoretical
{2: 0.5, 3: 0.333333, 4: 0.125, 5: 0.033333, 6: 0.006944, 7: 0.00119, 8: 0.000174, 9: 2.2e-05}
```

And just to check that this is a legit distribution:

```
>>> sum(p(k) for k in range(2,500))
0.9999999999999999
```